# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, prototype-js

I have a custom theme in which a certain template uses jQuery - everything works like a charm. I put the changes in the template from the default theme - everything OK. This is on my developer machine.

Then I put the changes, in both the custom and the default themes, on the testing machine (another, separate machine) and it works with the custom theme, but does not on the default theme. When debugging in FireBug, I get thrown exception on this line of code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

whereas I get the `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` exception. This is weird, because the code on the dev machine and on the testing machine is completely identical for both the custom and the default themes.

Comment: Make sure the jquery file is included in the dom. Also you may try to clear the cache. Maybe the layout that includes the jquery file is cached to an older version.

Comment: @Marius - cache is not the problem - everything was cleared. Also the jQuery library is included in the `default/layout/page.xml` in the `head` tag and I added a `$.noConflict();` script in the `header.phtml` file of the theme. Still the same problem.

Comment: How do you load jquery: google cdn or locally? Also, do you merge js files?

Comment: do you have the merge js/css files option set?